# Enemy Logic | Bullets Resetting

Tags: c++, events, sfml

First off I'd like to say I'm still very inexperienced, I only started programming last week.

I'm currently developing my first game (and C++ application), I've run into a problem, and haven't managed to solve it, and I'm starting to give up.

I can spawn enemies correctly, but now I want each of them to shoot once each second. The code I'm using for this is as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            if (enemy_basic[i].getPositionY() >= -100 && enemy_basic[i].getPositionY() <= 900)
            {
                if (enemyBasicLaserNumber[i] < 200 && enemyLaserTimer[i].getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 1) 
                {
                    enemy_laser[enemyBasicLaserNumber[i]].setPosition(enemy_basic[i].getPositionX(), enemy_basic[i].getPositionY());
                    enemyLaserTimer[i].restart();
                    enemyBasicLaserNumber[i]++;
                    cout << enemyBasicLaserNumber[i] << endl;
                }

                if (enemyBasicLaserNumber[i] >= 199) enemyBasicLaserNumber[enemyBasicNumber] = 0;
            }
        }
```

Now, I know there's something wrong in there somewhere, because the bullets keep getting reset back to enemy as soon as there are multiple enemies on screen (as long as it's only 1 enemy it works perfectly), and I still haven't managed to figure out what needs changing, or if I need to do this in an entirely different way.

If someone could just point me in the right direction or help me out in some way, I'd be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

You should structure your code in a more appropriate Object oriented style. You could create a base class Entity which contains a virtual function update. It also should contains the reference/pointer parent of the entity.

```
class SceneManager
{
public:
    SceneManager();
    virtual ~SceneManager();

    //put your own parameters
    Bullet& createBullet(/* */);

private:
    //a list of pointers for polymorphism
    boost::ptr_list<Entity> entities_;
};

class Entity
{
public:
    Entity(SceneManager& smgr);
    virtual ~Entity();

    virtual void update(const float timedelta) = 0;
private:
    const int id_;
    static int count_ = 0;
protected:
    SceneManager& smgr_;

    //local scale, rotation
    Transform transform_;

    //position
    Vector3d position_;

    //the model,sprite representation
    char drawable_;
};

class Enemy:public Entity
{
public:
    Enemy(SceneManager& smgr);
    virtual ~Enemy();

    virtual void update(const float timedelta);
    void shoot();
};

class Bullet:public Entity
{
public:
    Bullet(SceneManager& smgr);
    virtual ~Bullet();

    virtual void update(const float timedelta);
};

void Enemy::update(const float timedelta)
{
    //shooting each second
    static float shootDelay = 1;

    static Timer timer;

    //check if timer has started
    if(!timer.started)
        timer.start();

    //if the timer has reached the desired delay
    if(timer.elapsed() > shootDelay)
    {
        shoot();
        timer.restart();
    }
}

void Enemy::shoot()
{
    //create the bullet via the scenemanager
    smgr_.createBullet(/******/);
}
```

This code is only symbolic code, you will have to use the existing libraries to actually implement the structure. This way of coding is used notably by the Irrlicht and Ogre3D graphic engines, but can be applied as well to the core logic of a game engine.

Comment: Yea, I knew there was a better way to structure my code than how it is right now, but I don't know which resources are good for learning. Should I be looking for books, tutorials on OOP, or just look at an open source game? Would be cool if you could point me in the right direction, thanks!